# IE blockUI & jquery issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, nivo-slider, blockui, jquery-blockui

I have a list of products that if you click on the link it will get the attribute and it will start the BlockUI plugin and will show a different image that have the same attribute as ID.

I'm also using a nivo slider that has a rotation of images with the same attributes and triggers the blockui on click. 
But in IE the blockui on the slider is not working.

This is the function that activates the blockui on the slider images:

```
$('#slider a, #htmlcaption span').click(function(){      

  getpen = $(this).attr('pen');
  console.log(getpen);
  $.blockUI({message: $("#" + getpen), 
      css: { 
        top: '3%',
        left: ($(window).width() - 654) /2 + 'px',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        border: 'none'
      }  
    }); 
    $("#" + getpen + " span").click($.unblockUI);

});
```

In IE the console.log is not working and I have no idea how to start fixing it. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

IE does not have the  **console**  object..

This is the reason for your error.. It will be only available if Developer tools is open.

Try commenting that line or use alert instead.

Comment: Check for any errors on the page by opening the Developer tools >.